# Reassignment of $this in PHP

Tags: php, scope, this

(*I understand this may be a touchy decision, but I'd appreciate we avoid answers such as "Please don't."*)

I have a class whose constructor takes a callback as an argument. In this callback, I think it would be most semantically correct that the `$this` variable be available as a reference to the instance to which the callback belongs. (*I've noticed that 5.4 has reinstated `$this` in the context of anonymous functions **defined within** a class, however even that change wouldn't help here as the function is passed as an argument to the constructor as mentioned*)

The issue comes from the fact that the instance is not being passed as an argument to the callback, but instead made available by `use()`

`use()` has the tendency to cry about `$this`, stating it cannot be used as a lexical variable.

Is there a way, without passing it as an argument (*any approach, `use()` or not, is likely fine*) to accomplish this?

Off hand, the only thing I can think of would be something like:

```
 ... function($foo, $bar)
    use($array_with_this){
        extract($array_with_this); // contains instance with key 'this'

        // code using $this

    } ...
```

But this is forcing an additional requirement, which I'd rather not need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$that = $this;
cb(function () use ($that) {
    $that-> ...
});
```

This `$this` is a special keyword, you cannot use it outside of an object context. And anonymous functions currently run outside of the of the object context. This will change in the next version of PHP (5.4) apparently.

Comment: Thanks @deceze. That's what I'm doing already. And the new PHP version won't actually solve this, despite the changes made to `$this` with respect to an instance. Anything like the `$GLOBALS['this'] = ...` or the `extract(array('this' => ...))` trick that would help here?

Comment: So, anonymous functions will run within the context they are called from? So if I call them from within a Class they will have the restrictions of the class they are called within?

Comment: @Bracket And I'm afraid it's the only solution for the time being.

Comment: @Mark No, the context is entirely lost, if I remember correctly. So you couldn't even access `protected` or `private` members.

Comment: @Bracket The real problem is that `$this` is a *magic variable*. `$this` always means *"the current object"*. You can't use "`$this`" to hand an object around.

Comment: @deceze - Yea, I understand that PHP reserves that name in the symbol table, but with tricks like what I mentioned, you can fool the engine into allowing `$this` to be used for anything. The problem is when calling `use()`, PHP must check the variable name for this exact purpose, despite being able to toss it around in global scope however you wish, after tricking PHP. Also, it's actually kind of unfortunate, what you pointed out regarding Mark's question. I've been using `call_user_func(function(){})` to escape from a given scope.

Comment: @Bracket PHP is not Javascript, don't overuse anonymous functions quite yet... :)

Comment: @deceze - Haha, oh I already have. I've built an entire HMVC-like framework on them. In any case, I trust you are correct that it cannot be done (*I had to sort of expect that*) however I'll let this question sit for a bit before I mark your answer, just to give others a shot in case some backdoor-hackish-mess of a solution exists.